# Use mediaelement to randomly play files in a folder chosen through folderpicker

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am new to WPF and Windows Universal Apps. I have an old desktop app that I want to recreate as a universal app. It will allow a user to specify a folder (through folder picker) and then the mediaElement will play random files from that folder.  I got the player to play files when chosen through the filepicker, but so far I have not been able to figure out how to play any files in a folder chosen through the folderpicker.  When I have them choose the folder to grant permission to it and then try to set the source to the absolute uri of a file in that folder I still get the following error "MF_MEDIA_ENGINE_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED : HRESULT - 0x80070005".  Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: That did it! Thanks Alan Yao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we try to play a media file in the folder you picked by folder picker, we need to open the file using StorageFile.OpenAsync. And set the opened stream to MediaElement as below:

```
    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");

        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (folder != null)
        {
            //get the file list
            var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName).AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

            //For example, I can use the following code to play the first item
            if (files.Count > 0)
            {
                var stream = await files[0].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

                await Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    mediaElement.SetSource(stream, files[0].ContentType);
                    mediaElement.Play();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```